# Efficiency of flatMap vs map followed by reduce in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd, flatmap

I have a text file sherlock.txt containing multiple lines of text. I load it in spark-shell using:

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("sherlock.txt")
```

My purpose is to count the number of words in the file. I came across two alternative ways to do the job.

First using flatMap:

```
textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).count()
```

Second using map followed by reduce:

```
textFile.map(line => line.split(" ").size).reduce((a, b) => a + b)
```

Both yield the same result correctly. I want to know the differences in time and space complexity of the above two alternative implementations, if indeed there is any ?

Does the scala interpreter convert both into the most efficient form ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will argue that the most idiomatic way to handle this would be to `map` and `sum`:

```
textFile.map(_.split(" ").size).sum
```

but the end of the day a total cost will be dominated by `line.split(" ")`.

You could probably do a little bit better by iterating over the string manually and counting consecutive whitespaces instead of building new `Array` but I doubt it is worth all the fuss in general.

If you prefer a little bit deeper insight [`count` is defined as](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3f49e0766f3a369a44e14632de68c657773b7a27/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1103):

```
def count(): Long = sc.runJob(this, Utils.getIteratorSize _).sum
```

where `Utils.getIteratorSize` is pretty much a naive iteration over `Iterator` with a sum of ones and [`sum` is equivalent to](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8ef3399aff04bf8b7ab294c0f55bcf195995842b/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/DoubleRDDFunctions.scala#L33)

```
_.fold(0.0)(_ + _)
```